# Yii2 добавить или убрать категории в поиск через запрос query

Tags: php, yii2, запрос

есть поиск на сайте, к модели цепляется поведение

```
'search' => [
                'class' => SearchBehavior::className(),
                'searchScope' => function ($model) {
                    /** @var \yii\db\ActiveQuery $model */
                    $model->select(['title', 'description']);
                    //$model->andWhere([]); тут по идее должна быть строка с добавлением или исключением категории
                },
                'searchFields' => function ($model) {
                    return [
                        ['name' => 'title', 'value' => $model->title],
                        ['name' => 'description', 'value' => $model->description],
                    ];
                }
            ],
```

В модели есть поле с id категории.

Comment: Доброй ночи. Доработайте свой вопрос, что-то не понятно, что надо Вам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброй ночи.

Ну так вот и добавляйте

```
$model->select(['title', 'description'])->where(['<>', 'category_id', 123]);
// or
$model->select(['title', 'description']);
$model->where(['<>', 'category_id', 123]);
```

Если Вам надо будет добавить ещё одно условие, то тогда уже используйте andWhere();

```
$model->select(['title', 'description'])
      ->where(['<>', 'category_id', 123])
      ->andWhere([*****]);
// or
$model->select(['title', 'description']);
$model->where(['<>', 'category_id', 123]);
$model->andWhere([*******]);
```

Answer (score 1):

нужно было после `$model->select(['title', 'description']);`
добавить условие `$model->andWhere(['<>', 'category_id', 123]);`